# Trying to hide model when clicked outside has different effects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue modal component which I make visible/invisible depending on a boolean variable, I also want to hide the modal when the user clicks outside the modal, I do this by attaching a click listener and checking each click to see if its outside or inside however there must be something wrong with my approach becuase the modal automatically closes right after I click the button to make it visible.

This is my component:

```
<template>
<transition name="cart-tab">
<div class="ADMINsearch_maincontainer" v-show="filtersVisible" id="admin-search">

</div>
</transition>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
export default {
name: 'LAYOUTsearch',


computed:
{
    ...mapState('AdminPanel',['filtersVisible', 'panelSchema', 'theme', 'searchSchema']),
},


data(){
    return {
    specifiedElement:null
    }

},


mounted()
{
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');
    this.addListener();
},


methods:
{



    addListener()
    {
        this.specifiedElement = document.getElementById('admin-search')
        const self = this;

        document.addEventListener('click', function(event) 
        {
            var isClickInside = self.specifiedElement.contains(event.target);

            if (!isClickInside) 
            {
                //outside
                self.setFiltersVisible(false)
            }
            else 
            {
                //inside
            }

        });
    },


}


};
</script>
<!--STYLES-->
<style scoped>
.container_style{width:100% !important;}
.ADMINsearch_maincontainer{width:33%; height:100vh; z-index:9999999999999999; background-color:white; box-shadow:-3px -3px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); position:fixed; top:0px; right:0px; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that you are getting the value of the variable `filtersVisible` trough mapState, then you are trying to update its value with a method in the component instance.

Let's suppose a store with this configuration:

```
const state = {
  filtersVisible: false
}

const mutations = {
  setFiltersVisibleValue(state, visible) {
    state.filtersVisible = visible
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
}
```

In the component you can set and get the state of the `filtersVisible` variable this way:

```
<template>
  <transition name="cart-tab">
    <div
      class="ADMINsearch_maincontainer"
      v-show="filtersVisible"
      id="admin-search"
    ></div>
  </transition>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "LAYOUTsearch",

  computed: {
    ...mapState(["filtersVisible"])
  },

  data() {
    return {
      specifiedElement: null
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$options.name + " component successfully mounted");
    this.addListener();
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["setFiltersVisibleValue"]),
    addListener() {
      this.specifiedElement = document.getElementById("admin-search");

      document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var isClickInside = self.specifiedElement.contains(event.target);

        if (!isClickInside) {
          //outside - call the mutation to update properly the value of the filtersVisible variable in the store
          this.setFiltersVisibleValue(false);
        } else {
          //inside
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
<!--STYLES-->
<style scoped>
.container_style{width:100% !important;}
.ADMINsearch_maincontainer{width:33%; height:100vh; z-index:9999999999999999; background-color:white; box-shadow:-3px -3px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); position:fixed; top:0px; right:0px; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
}
</style>
```

- The example is using only the variable `filtersVisible` for the explanation purpose. I'm assuming a Vuex store that is not using modules.